# A word for words that are often seen in their negative forms

Tags: negation

Words like "misconstrue" or "disgruntled" are fairly common. But you much less commonly see the word "construe" or "gruntled"

Is there a term for words like this?

Comment: Construe is not that uncommon vs misconstrue:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=construe%2C+misconstrue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconstrue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmisconstrue%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm plussed. :(

Comment: *Ruly* may be a better candidate than *construe.* There are also others.

Comment: *I am such a dolent man,\I eptly work each day;\My acts are all becilic,\I've just ane things to say.* (attributed to a J. H. Parker.) Phrases Org  http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/20/messages/136.html

Answer (score 4):

These words are called *[Absent Antonyms](http://www.2wheels.org.uk/return/absent-antonyms.asp)* or *[Unpaired Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpaired_word)*.

> *absent antonym:* ...negative-looking words commonly found in the English language whose presumed positive forms are rarely, or never, found. [2wheels.org.uk]
>
> *unpaired word:* ...is one that, according to the usual rules of the language, would appear to have a related word but does not. Such words usually have a prefix or suffix that would imply that there is an antonym, with the prefix or suffix being absent or opposite. [wikipedia]

Some of them end up with matching antonyms as a result of *[back-formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation)* (sometimes as a jocular back-formation like *gruntled* as opposed to *disgruntled*), or had antonyms in the past which fell out of use.

There is also the term *[lonely negatives](http://mentalfloss.com/article/49720/12-lonely-negative-words)* used at mentalfloss.com. However, they are defined as "negative words whose positive partners have vanished or never existed in the first place." Common examples: *Disgusted, disgruntled* and *disheveled*.

Comment: Seems like all the alternatives apply to cases where the pairing word just doesn't exist or is never used, not where it is uncommon.

Comment: @Kris: There are cases that the antonym is uncommon.

Comment: Then why do we call them "absent," "unpaired," or "lonely"?

Comment: @Kris: Probably because, most of the time there isn't an antonym or it is very rare. I didn't coin them though :)

Comment: There! I was thinking just that -- no one coined them as such, someone used the nonce phrases to make their point. So I suspect there's really no name or a term that officially defines. Just my 2c.