# Why don't we say things are pervious?

Tags: etymology, antonyms, history, prefixes

Why is the word "pervious" uncommon to the point of being considered a spelling error, but "impervious" is extremely common?

For the record, it *is* a word, apparently. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pervious) defines it as:

> 1. admitting of passage or entrance; permeable: pervious soil.
> 2. open or accessible to reason, feeling, argument, etc.

My general sense is that these kinds of opposites (formed with *in-*, *im-*, etc.) tend to be either well balanced in usage, or the "positive" form is more common. Consider:

- perfect / imperfect
- possible / impossible
- plausible / implausible

[Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perfect%2Cimperfect%2Cpossible%2Cimpossible%2Cplausible%2Cimplausible&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperfect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimperfect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpossible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpossible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplausible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimplausible%3B%2Cc0) support this perception:

[image: NGram of various common words]

There are a few exceptions to this rule of thumb. "Insurmountable" seems more common than "surmountable," for example. This is again reinforced with an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insurmountable%2Csurmountable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsurmountable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csurmountable%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

The word "pervious" seems so odd that at first I thought that the word "impervious" must have derived from some completely different source and the presence of *im-* was just a coincidence. But, no, the etymology clearly points to a root where the positive form "pervious" (from the Latin "pervius") is (was?) valid.

[image: etymology of impervious]

I've considered that the word is just too similar to the abbreviated form of "pervert," which obviously has a strong negative connotation. But this doesn't appear to be a well-reasoned or satisfying answer. Lots of perfectly valid words are superficially similar to words with negative connotations. (Think of a "niggling" pain, for example, although admittedly this example is more common in British English and the racial slur it's similar to is likely more common in American English.) Bottom line, I doubt that people aren't using "pervious" because it's similar to other words.

So this leaves me wondering:

1. What happened to the word "pervious"? Why is it so much less common than "impervious"?
2. Is there a known class of such words where the opposite (formed by a prefix) of a word is dramatically more common than its base?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: My thought is that That's The Way It Is.

Comment: There's rarely a need to use the word, especially given that "porous" or "permeable" usually captures the intended meaning as well, if not better.  I have seen uses such as "the material is pervious to petroleum solvents", however.

Comment: I think because there are other common alternatives that people used more frequently throughout the history and "pervious" is mostly used in technical context, especially in pavement engineering. For example, there is a difference between *pervious, permeable*, and *porous* pavers: http://stormwater.wef.org/2013/10/pervious-permeable-porous-pavers-really/

Comment: I answered the second question here: [A word for words that are often seen in their negative forms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230416/a-word-for-words-that-are-often-seen-in-their-negative-forms)

Comment: According to Google ngrams, [pervious used to be more common than permeable](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pervious%2Cpermeable%2Cimpervious%2Cimpermeable&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpervious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpermeable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpervious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpermeable%3B%2Cc0) until about 1867, and is still used

Comment: @ermanen good link.  Makes me feel combobulated.

Comment: I'm surprised that the choate, sipid, and ept contributors to this site have not pointed to this little classic  [link](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/humor/how-i-met-my-wife.html)

Comment: It may be worth noting that the "pervious" that appears in many Google Books results (14 pages' worth of results, just from 2015) are typos of "previous".

Comment: This question reminded me of Josh's answer, the [antonym of *ruthless* is *ruthful*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263435/is-there-an-antonym-of-ruthless) I'd wager that *ruthful* is much rarer than *pervious*.

Comment: There are also other Latin-based words where the negative is more common, like *indubitabl[e/y]* and *inevitabl[e/y]*.

Comment: *Pervious* is hardly dead in technical and scientific writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *pervious*/*impervious* pair makes a nice double-foursome with *penetrable*/*impenetrable*, *permeable*/*impermeable*, and *pregnable*/*impregnable*. All four pairs involve the notion of yielding or refusing to yield to incursion or intrusion, and all register at least some matches on Google Books and its related Ngram.

But though some of these word pairs receive equal respect from dictionary makers, none enjoy truly balanced use in print (and presumably in speech). Here is how the Ngram charts for the years 1700–2005 look for each pair.

For *penetrable* (blue line) versus *impenetrable* (red line):

[image]

For *permeable* (blue line) versus *impermeable* (red line):

[image]

For *pervious* (blue line) versus *impervious* (red line):

[image]

And for *pregnable* (blue line) versus *impregnable* (red line):

> [image]

Of the four pairs, only *permeable*/*impermeable* shows anything close to competitive balance. But until 1900 or so, the next-most competitive pair was *pervious*/*impervious*, which is surprising in part because *pervious* doesn't receive as much respect from (for example) the EL&U spelling checker as *penetrable* does, despite the latter's prolonged weak showing against *impenetrable*. (All eight words appear in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* [2003], however, and the Eleventh Collegiate is very far from being an unabridged dictionary.

But the Ngram chart for *pervious*/*impervious* also unmistakably shows that people do say that things are *pervious*. In fact, as this Ngram chart of *penetrable* (blue line) versus *permeable* (red line) versus *pervious* (green line) versus *pregnable* (yellow line) for the years 1750–2005 shows, they use it more than they use *pregnable* and about as much as they use *penetrable*:

[image]

The [Google Books search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pervious%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) behind the Ngram chart show that *pervious* is especially widely used in connection with soil and with concrete, asphalt, and other forms of surfacing and pavement.

With regard to why some words that have been in use for decades suddenly or gradually fall out of favor, I think language and competing word choices are so  complicated that you would be unlikely to isolate the cause even in a particular instance—and as for reaching a generally applicable truth about how words rise and fall, good luck with that...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Colin Fine and Hot Licks that 'pervious' is less in need (and would likely be misunderstood).  We manage without a positive form of 'bullet-proof vest'. We also don't use corrigible much: Imagine asking one's math teacher if your answer that lost you marks is 'corrigible'.